# Excel function to determine count for range of an occurrence text value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I know this is a simple function to implement in excel but I am not getting it right. I am trying to get count of "FAIL" text where "THUMB" using this function `=IF(L8:L307="THUMB",COUNTIF(N8:N307,"*FAIL*"))` but then I am getting `#VALUE!`. I want to be able to tell how many FAILs are there for the occurence of THUMB.

Here is a screenshot from my excel worksheet I am working on
[image]

Could someone please tell me what is it that I am doing wrong in this function?

Comment: I think you're really after `=COUNTIFS(L8:L307,"THUMB",N8:N307,"*FAIL*")`.

Comment: That was fast. I have tried your formula and it works perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you gotta use the simple `countifs` function like this:

```
=COUNTIFS($N$8:$N$307,"FAIL",$L$8:$L$307,"THUMB")
```

hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you AHC, your formula too was correct. Much appreciated. I have compared my results using both your formula and that of Phylogenesis suggested below my post and they both give the same results. I appreciate.